# UIPickerView does not update on other ViewController after countdown timer

Tags: swift, timer, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview, alpha

I have an options ViewController where the user can change the password and  a pickerView. Whenever he presses the save button a timer starts and the user gets directed to the main screen through a segue. I want to be able to grey the pickerView out for a certain amount of time (on the options ViewController) as soon as the user presses this save button (it equals a time-based restriction).
My problem now is that anytime the user presses the button and gets directed to the main screen, the pickerview.alpha on the options ViewController (which i set for the grey out effect) will not change / the change is not visible when the user returns in the time period. Also the pickerview.alpha is not changing back on the options ViewController screen when the time period expieres.

So in order to follow my describtion here is my code so far:

```
import UIKit        

class OptionsViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate

 @IBOutlet var PickerView: UIPickerView!

 var seconds = 20
 var timer = Timer() 
 var isTimerRunning = false

 @IBAction func Save_Touched(_ sender: Any) {
     if isTimerRunning == false {
         runTimer()
     }
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromOptionstoMainSegue", sender: self)
 }

 func runTimer() {
     timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(OptionsViewController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     self.PickerView.alpha = 0.5
     isTimerRunning = true
 }

 func updateTimer() {
     if seconds < 1 {
         timer.invalidate()
         self.PickerView.alpha = 1.0
     } else {
         seconds -= 1
         print(seconds)
     }
 }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     self.PickerView.dataSource = self
     self.PickerView.delegate = self

     print(isTimerRunning)  
 }
}
```

I tried endless options in order to achieve it, but could not make it.
Therefore i am really looking forward to any answer or help!

With kind regards

Comment: First of all, you better invalidate and nullify the timer before you run `scheduledTimer`. NSTimer has strong reference once it is added to main run loop. Check [NSTimer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer)

Comment: @Ryan, it's better if you have a clickable link. To do this, you put the word that you want OP to click in square brackets, and immediately following that, you surround the link in parentheses. So, your link would be [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimer).

Comment: Did you check `runTimer` is called every second? What does `fromOptionstoMainSegue` do exactly?

Comment: @Ryan `fromOptionstoMainSegue` follows after the button press and describes the segue which takes the user from the options ViewController to the Main screen

Comment: To make things clear, `UIPickerView` is on the `OptionsViewController`. Once user pressed `save` button, timer begins and present `Main` viewcontroller. And once timer reaches 0, you want to show `UIPickerView` again?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily disable the pickerView. Either hide it completely:

```
PickerView.isHidden = true
```

then unhide it later, or just simply disable it:

```
PickerView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

and enable it again after your save is finished. There is no need to grey out the pickerView.

EDIT:

There is nothing wrong with your code for setting the alpha of your picker view. Make sure your outlet is linked to the picker view in the storyboard.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! The UserInteraction would be the next step
 but for the overall appealingof the application it looks better if the PickerView is greysih when it is disabled

Comment: I don't think this is an answer. Also @cod3r3 sets alpha in `runTimer()` method, so it will be transparent as soon as timer begins.

Comment: OP sets the alpha right **after** the timer begins, so it won't run, but @Ryan you have a good point. I'm editing my post.

Comment: Why do you think you can't change alpha after timer begins? That is totally not true.